Is there a way for me to manage variables dynamically in Robot Framework?
Instead of creating too many variables that suit every test case, I want a way to modify variables dynamically in Variables section .
For example, for the variable ${X}      211
and for the next test, I want the same variable to change its value to
${X}    210
*** Variables ***

${statut_Motif_defaut}    200
# Valeur ID
${id_Presta}    Hello_
${id_migra}    3333

*** Keywords ***
Update Statut Motif Défaut
    [Arguments]    ${new_value}
    Set Suite Variable    ${statut_Motif_defaut}    ${new_value}

# Met à jour la variable dynamique

*** Test Cases ***
TC_1: Test 1
    Update Statut Motif Défaut    210
    Log Statut Motif Défaut

TC_2: Test 2
    Update Statut Motif Défaut    220
    Log Statut Motif Défaut

the value to be changed in every test .
